# autoload['helper'] = array('url'); how can i load url helper by this a way like codeigniter

Tags: php, autoloader

At this time I want to build a MVC framework. Everything is going fine but now i want to add another function (autoload classes like codeigniter). For exemple in my autoload.php I have:

```
$autoload['helpers'] = array('url');
```

How can I load the url class by this?

Comment: I agree that the documentation is a little lacking here. I am also having an issue and need to see a working example to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty slimmed down, but the concept would be something like below.  You can look at CI's autoloading ways in it's `/system/core/Loader.php` file.

```
foreach($autoload['helpers'] as $helper)
{
    include_once($your_base_path . $path_to_helpers . $helper . '.php');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009682/how-do-i-load-codeigniter-helpers-in-every-page). but here are some examples:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','ion_auth');
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of helpers, Aaron's example is great, but if you want extra classes, you probably want to create their instances too:

```
$autoload = array();
$autoload['libraries'] = array('url');

foreach($autoload as $set)
{
    foreach($set as $class)
    {
        if(file_exists($set.'/'.$class.'.php'))
        {
            require_once($set.'/'.$class.'.php');
            $this->$class = new $class;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could possibly do this easily much like how codeigniter does it, by building an array, the iterating through the array and using the standard loading class like here on [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php).  since this is your own MVC framework you're trying to build, you can add as an extension to your framework the Zend::autoloader.  i assume you'll have a config file, and within there you can define your library include like if you were to use Pear or any other extended libraries, you can just pull out all the Zend classes and just extend from that.  when i use codeigniter, i generally add Zend as an extension to make the framework more robust and not to reinvent the wheel.

here's a reference link to incorporate [zend with codeigniter](http://www.mynameisphil.net/article/may/2009/implementing-the-zend-framework-with-codeigniter/11), it's fairly old and some adjustment will probably need to be made to match the current codeigniter release.

i hope this helps.