# How do I load CodeIgniter helpers in every page?

Tags: php, templates, codeigniter, view, controller

I have a view, header.php, that gets loaded in various controller methods. It contains my opening html tag, a base tag for my relative links, and some meta tags that I call in every page of my application. Is there way to load the helpers that render the meta tags and base url so that they are available to header.php every time it is loaded without having to include `$this->load->helper('html');` and `$this->load->helper('url');` every time I `$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);` in a controller to load header.php?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're needing these that often, you should just add those to your helpers autoload:

In [/application/config/autoload.php](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/autoload.php) around line 93, change

```
$autoload['helper'] = array();
```

to

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('html', 'url');
```

Then, they're loaded on every request.

Comment: Is html is the name of file that is in helper?

Comment: @NomanJaved - yes, it is. here's the docs to the CI2 autoload array: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/autoloader.html

Answer (score 0):

Simple, add them to the autoload file. That way they'll be accessible from any file, and you won't ever have to call those.