# Codeigniter: A fatal error occurs when using base_url() function to define a constant in "application/config/constants.php" file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter and right now I'm trying to define some constants to hold full paths to some folders like css, js, images, etc. and I've tried to define these constants in `application/config/constants.php` file like this:

```
define("PATH_TO_CSS_FOLDER", base_url("assets/css"));
```

but I've got this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function base_url() in D:\xampp\htdocs\demo\application\config\constants.php on line 44
```

so how can I define these constants without having to write the absolute path in the constants.php file like this:

```
define("PATH_TO_CSS_FOLDER", "http://my-website.com/assets/css");
```

Comment: How do you load the helper function?
Probably you should use autoloading process as described here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009682/how-do-i-load-codeigniter-helpers-in-every-page

Comment: @james_bond I already load the url helper exactly like that mentioned in the approved answer you've referred to

Comment: Beside the right answer of "Rajeev Ranjan" which I've accepted, I also found this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13825685/458204 for another similar question, and I've found that it is really a great solution for the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can define rest of path in constant.php

```
define("PATH_TO_CSS_FOLDER","assets/css");
```

use it later in ohter places

```
<?php echo base_url(PATH_TO_CSS_FOLDER);?>
```

you might be knowing that constants loads first then any helper

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the url helper to access that function. Either you add

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

somewhere in your controller, or you can put it into the application/config/autoload.php to be loaded automatically everywhere.

you have to use echo before `base_url()` function. otherwise it woudn't print the base url. like

`echo base_url();`

Comment: I already have url helper autoloaded, and that didn't fix the problem

Comment: Did u try site_url() ?

Comment: you have to use echo before base_url() function. otherwise it woudn't print the base url.

Comment: Yes I did, and it is the same as base_url() returns a fatal error